# TS/SFC/RenderProp: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to Typescript and have most of my errors resolved, but I'm not sure what to do about this one. Given this component...

```
const CurrentUser: React.SFC = props => (
  <Query {...props} query={CURRENT_USER_QUERY}>
    {payload => props.children(payload)}
  </Query>
)
```

I'm seeing these errors. I don't understand how children could ever be null or undefined. Aren't they guaranteed if the object is an SFC? How do I resolve this?

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'

[image]

## Update 3/3/2019

Because of BlackICE's comment, I eventually realized that I needed to check that children exists before I invoke it. Duh! But now I have a different problem

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | number | true | {} | ReactElement | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal' has no compatible call signatures.

[image]

Comment: that `?` after the name of children property on props means it can be null.

Comment: @BlackICE True, but why would that be? I guess if it were a self closing component `<CurrentUser />` it could be, but since this is a render prop, that should never be. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you think that SFC can't be used as self-closing?

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't. I realized if it we're, children would be null

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, here is the final solution...

```
type Props = {
  children: (a: QueryResult) => JSX.Element
}

const CurrentUser: React.SFC<Props> = props => (
  <Query {...props} query={CURRENT_USER_QUERY}>
    {payload => props.children && props.children(payload)}
  </Query>
)
```

where `QueryResult` is imported from `react-apollo`

```
import { Query, QueryResult } from 'react-apollo'
```